# Upload test results to Sqhub for Node js with GitHub Actions

Tags: node.js, bash, express, github-actions, cloud-foundry

Working on creating a new node js app with express using GitHub Actions for CI/CD. I am using internal re-usable workflows for Build & Test, Upload to artifactory, and deploy to Clod Foundry for deployment. While Uploading the test results to Sqhub pipeline passed, but is unable to publish the test results QualityHub Dashboard for new app.
Node.js = 16

Build & Test Internal Re-usable workflow:

```
name: Upload
id:sqhub
uses: company/sqhub-action@v1.3
with app-name: apple
test-results-location: test-results
```

Error from GitHub Actions pipeline:

```
find: 'test-results':No such file or directory
tar: test-results/testresults.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application

Upload successful
SQHUb Results: <Link to sqhub>
But in Sqhub side there is nothing. We created an app in Sqhub side. 
Add a new token in GitHub Repo in secrets tab with QUALITYHUB_TOKEN.
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to add **jest-junit** dependency in package.json and add **jest.config.js** file in project root directory. In this file I mention the test result output directory as -test-results. Next I add, anything in test folder with .js file to detect test files as like this -> `testMatch:[ "/tests/*.js"]`. In GitHub Actions, upload to test results are successful.